# Cannot remove a symlink ("Is a directory")

Tags: centos, symlink

I created a symlink:

[image]

Then I decided to remove it:

[image]

But I can't. What is going on here? I don't want to force the removal as I am afraid to not affect in any way the original. Operating system is CentOS 5.9. Any advice on how to **safely** remove the symlink are most welcome!

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Try `/bin/rm -iv /galaxy` (I guess `rm` has a shell alias)

Comment: Those code blocks are screen shots!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a directory /galaxy, and the symbolic link you created is in that directory, /galaxy/galaxy.

To remove the symlink do: rm /galaxy/galaxy